# Firewall/browser extension removing user information from POSTed form?

Tags: web-development, forms, firewall

I have a web form that requests basic user information such as user name, address and email from the user.  The form has basic JavaScript validation to make sure the user provides the required information in order to continue.

The form uses a combination of POST and GET through short series of questions.  However, I routinely receive the form at the server with the basic user information missing.

Is the information possibly being stripped out by a firewall?  A browser extension? If so, is there a way to verify this or to work around it?

Comment: Client side validation isn't very robust.  Can you implement server side validation too?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, I could.  While some missing data appears to be intentionally missing, other times it doesn't appear the users are intentionally leaving out data.

Comment: Maybe they have javascript disabled.  I use the **required** attribute rather than javascript. but that can also be altered.  Why aren't you checking the validity in the **POST**ed page and asking the user to re-enter the information ?

Comment: @RohitGupta, it's a WordPress plugin and I hesitate to add custom functions specific to a plugin even in my own library files.  However, server side validation may be the only option I have.